# How to stop automatic apt update?

Tags: apt, upgrade

I have uninstalled the package `unattended-upgrades` (debian bullseye), but this only stopped the `upgrade` part, not the `update` part: when I run `apt list --upgradable`, without `sudo apt update`, I can still see new upgradable packages show up from time to time. What is going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

APT itself includes a daily task to update its indexes. Nowadays this is a systemd timer, which you can disable:

```
systemctl disable apt-daily.timer
```

If you have PackageKit installed, it will also check for updates periodically. On GNOME, you can control this through the Software application; in its main menu, it has an “Update Preferences” entry which leads to this dialog:

[image: GNOME Software Update Preferences dialog, showing the automatic update configuration controls]

Disabling automatic updates should disable PackageKit’s updates.

Alternatively, you can disable the PackageKit service:

```
systemctl disable --now packagekit.service
```

or you can uninstall the `gnome-software` package since that’s what’s driving PackageKit here.