# Debian revision suffixes - why do they change during apt upgrade when I have not run apt update?

Tags: debian, apt

For example, I have the `libxml2` package installed. Its version is `2.9.4+dfsg1-2.2+deb9u4`.

What does the `u4` part mean at the end?

If I run `apt -y upgrade` *without* running `apt update` first, why will this upgrade the package to `2.9.4+dfsg1-2.2+deb9u5` (everything is the same, but now `u5` is on the end)?

Edit: I have noticed the same thing happen with many other packages, where they will upgrade with no `apt update` if the only thing changing is that final `u` number.

Answer (score 2):

`u4`, interpreted with `deb9`, means it’s the fourth update of `libxml2` for Debian 9 since the latter was released. You can see the details of each update in [the `libxml2` changelog for Debian 9](https://tracker.debian.org/media/packages/libx/libxml2/changelog-2.9.4dfsg1-2.2deb9u5).

The current version of `libxml2` for Debian 9 is 2.9.4+dfsg1-2.2+deb9u5, which was [published to Debian 9’s security repository on May 30](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1242001/accepted-libxml2-294dfsg1-22deb9u5-source-amd64-all-into-oldstable/). Presumably you’ve run `apt update` since then (or the system’s run it for you), but you haven’t upgraded.

> I have noticed the same thing happen with many other packages, where they will upgrade with no `apt update` if the only thing changing is that final `u` number.

`apt upgrade` *never* knows about changes unless `apt update` is run. This can happen automatically; `apt`’s default setup ensures it’s run daily. See [How to stop automatic apt update?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/594272/86440) for details.

The reason you only see `u` updates is that those are pretty much the *only* updates that happen inside a given release in Debian, apart from web browsers and the kernel. On a server, you will mostly see package upgrades where the version number bumps the `u` part, or adds it (if it’s the first such upgrades since the release). (There are some exceptions, typically when a project releases an update with *only* a bug fix which is important for Debian; see [`gdnsd`](https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/g/gdnsd/gdnsd_2.4.3-1_changelog) for a recent example in Debian 10.)

Comment: On my server, I'm 100% certain that no `apt update` was run in the time between that update becoming available on May 30th and the time that `apt upgrade` was run. I have noticed the same thing happen with many other packages, where it will upgrade without an `apt update` if the only thing changing in the version is that final `u` number. Why is this?

Comment: The fact that `apt upgrade` knows about the update means that I’m 100% sure that `apt update` *was* run, but it’s quite possible it wasn’t run *by you*. For example, what does `systemctl status apt-daily.timer` show?

Comment: As for why updates with `u` numbers show up, those are the *only* updates made to a stable release, apart from a few exceptions which shouldn’t affect servers (web browsers mainly). So on a stable release, you will only ever see updates which bump the `u` number (or add a `u` suffix, for the first such update).

Comment: Ok, so `apt-daily.timer` is running, I did not know this existed.